# send log of a desktop java application into server

Tags: java, logging, client-server

I am using

```
try{
}
catch(Exception e){
  Logger.getLogger(Terminal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
}
```

This exception will been thrown in users pc's and i will not be able to see it.
Is there a way to send the exception log into a server?

Comment: Do you think your code will compile first?

Comment: I don't understand you question. The program will run on user computer.if an exception is thrown there, i will never learn about it.

Comment: "catch{" where are you handling exception there?

Comment: Everywhere inside my code.I have around 30 classes and i am using try-catch for more than 100 hundred times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are using log4j library. If yes, you may want to use one of log4j appenders which supports sending logs to "server", for example `org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender` or `org.graylog2.log.GelfAppender`. Of course you have to run suitable application on your server which can accept logs sent by log4j appender at cilent site.